# Creating a loop that adds n+1 sequentially

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I am trying to create a loop which counts the number of "o" present in multiple columns and returns an n+1 for each time "o" is present.

So the code will do the following:

- For the first column, if cell = “o”, enter 1
- If cell is empty, leave it as is
- If cell = “o”, enter previous cell’s number + 1

I have tried to create the code but have been unsuccessful.

My data currently looks like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o | o | o | o |
|  | o | o |  |
| o |  |  | o |
|  | o |  |  |

And I want the loop to return the following results, either in new columns or in the existing columns:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|  | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 |  |  | 2 |
|  | 1 |  |  |

Comment: For a single row, `row[row == "o"] <- seq_len(sum(row == "o"))`. How to apply it to your data will depend on the structure... do you have a matrix or data frame? Could you provide the sample data in valid R syntax? Maybe `dput(your_data[1:4, 1:4])` so it's copy/pasteable?

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, \(x) {x[x=='o'] <- seq_len(sum(x=='o')); x}))
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to me to leave the cells empty. I'd rather have them as 0 or NA. Here's a solution that achieves that:

```
t(apply((df1 == "o"), 1, cumsum)) * (df1 == "o")
```